# PCF - dotnet_core_buildpack => Getting error exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: .net-core, cloud-foundry, pcf

I am getting an error => exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%

When I try to push the .Net Core 2 application to PCF.

The command I am using is  :

```
    cf push BTH -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack#v2.1.5
```

Updating app BTH...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 354.38 KiB / 354.38 KiB [=================================================================================] 100.00% 2s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

> Staging app and tracing logs...    Cell
>   f518b117-f7b5-49c7-a13b-5e4a803f5bf5 successfully created container
>   for instance d820ec8d-86d6-4662-bc24-ca23fa2a2557    Downloading app
>   package...    Downloaded app package (10.6M)    exec: "git":
>   executable file not found in %PATH%    Exit status 1    Cell
>   f518b117-f7b5-49c7-a13b-5e4a803f5bf5 stopping instance
>   d820ec8d-86d6-4662-bc24-ca23fa2a2557    Cell
>   f518b117-f7b5-49c7-a13b-5e4a803f5bf5 destroying container for instance
>   d820ec8d-86d6-4662-bc24-ca23fa2a2557    Cell
>   f518b117-f7b5-49c7-a13b-5e4a803f5bf5 successfully destroyed container
>   for instance d820ec8d-86d6-4662-bc24-ca23fa2a2557 Error staging
>   application: Staging error: staging failed FAILED

The staging gets failed.

Comment: It's saying `%PATH%` which is a windows-ism. Did you set the stack to a windows stack? The .netcore buildpack is for Linux stacks, like `cflinuxfs3`.

Comment: If I user linux, the I get this error => Error staging application: Staging error: staging failed
FAILED

Comment: That's not really enough info to say what is happening. You would need to include the full output from `cf push`, including the command and your manifest.yml (if you're using one).